# Can I connect Digital Ocean droplet/ digital ocean app(serverless) to domain that I bought in wix?

Tags: server, cloud, digital-ocean, velo

I have a domain that I bought in wix, Now I want to host my website in DIgital Ocean, How to connect droplet to wix domain

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Wix will probably use its name servers to ensure your domain's records are published. Wix provides a mechanism to manage your domain's records. You are able to add e.g. `A`, `CNAME`, `TXT` records.

See: [Adding DNS records in your Wix account](https://support.wix.com/en/article/adding-dns-records-in-your-wix-account).

Droplets will generally be published on the Internet using IP(v4) addresses. You will want to add `A`(ddress) DNS records to alias your chosen host name in your domain to the Droplet's IPv4 address. For exmaple, to reference your droplet as `droplet.[your-domain-name]`, you would create an `A` record with host name `droplet` with value set to the droplet's IP address.

Apps are published using `SOMETHING.ondigitalocean.app` (DNS) name. You will want to add `CNAME` DNS records to alias your chosen host name in your domain to the App's DNS name. For example, to reference your DigitalOcean Apps as `app.[your-domain-name]`, you would create a `CNAME` record with host name `app` with value set to the app's `SOMETHING.ondigitalocean.app` name.